# Draw a shape, and make it bigger when user touches

Tags: android

I have seen how to draw a shape in Android, but what I want to know is how to rescale the shape when the user touches over the shape.

Imagine a square into a screen corner, so when you touch it, it grows until fitting the whole screen. I'd like to make that with a transition, animated, not instant.

Any idea of how to do that, or any known resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has built-in support for [Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View). You can find many examples by searching the Web. [This](http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/) one is a good start.

In order to make your shapes touchable, you can implement them by overriding the View class (a nice example can be found [here](http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/)). Then you can use [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

Comment: It is indeed a good start! But I still need to know how to detect user touches over the shapes. Sure, working with squares I could store it's bounds and when user touches anywhere check if it's into that bounds. Anywhere I'm not sure if this is the best/easiest approach. Any thought about that?

Comment: Also, is this the most CPU-efficient solution for doing this? I need it working on a very low-cost Android device

Comment: See my edited answer. As for the efficiency solution, I doubt there is a more efficient way than a built-in solution.

Answer (score 1):

The built in Animations are nice in Android but they aren't the most efficient by any means. When performance is a must I would recommend creating your own method. What I would do is create a class that extends `View` and give it a bounding box (Rect/RectF) and a circle. Then you can use the bounding box to detect when the circle is touched.

```
public class Circle extends View {
    public static final float SCALE_AMOUNT = 1.0f;
    public RectF boundingBox;
    private Paint paint;
    private float circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius;
    private float x, y;

    public Circle(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Create paint
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        // Set circle start radius
        circleRadius = 50.0f;

        // Set start x and y (this is the upper left hand corner)
        x = 100.0f;
        y = 100.0f;

        // Create boundingBox
        boundingBox = new RectF();
        boundingBox.left = x;
        boundingBox.top = y;
        boundingBox.right = x + (circleRadius*2);
        boundingBox.bottom = y + (circleRadius*2);

        // Set circleCenterX and circleCenterY (the center of the bounding box and circle)
        circleCenterX = x + circleRadius;
        circleCenterY = y + circleRadius;
    }

    public void scale(boolean scaleUp) {
        float scaleBy = (scaleUp) ? SCALE_AMOUNT : -SCALE_AMOUNT;

        // Update circleRadius
        circleRadius += scaleBy;

        // Update the bounding box
        boundingBox.left = x;
        boundingBox.top = y;
        boundingBox.right = x + (circleRadius*2);
        boundingBox.bottom = y + (circleRadius*2);

        // Update the circle center positions
        circleCenterX = x + circleRadius;
        circleCenterY = y + circleRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius, paint);
    }

}
```

... Then in your `Activity` class override the `onTouchEvent()` method and check if your `Circle` is touched.

```
Circle circle = new Circle(this);

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    circle.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    // Detect if pointer goes down on screen
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if(circle.boundingBox.contains(x, y) == true) {
            // Circle was touched so scale it
            circle.scale(true); // true is scale up, false is scale down
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

... This will scale your circle/rectangle every time you touch it. If you wanted to make it continually grow you could have a boolean variable that gets set to true when you touch the shape and grows until you pick your finger up. I haven't tried this code, just typed it up real quick so it may not compile but this is going to be you're best bet. It is really easy to add many shapes and detect touches on all of the shapes. Add different effects to each one... etc. I didn't want to do all of it for you but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this github project could help you: https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton